# Writing entire SQL table whenever data changes on a Node server (weird one, so bear with me)

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle

Okay, let me start by saying that I know this is weird. I do.

But here goes:

Let's say I have an SQL database which stores my data. And let's say I don't have a choice in this, it has to be SQL. The application I'm building has somewhere in the region of 100,000 records in its database, and once every single record has been processed by the users of the application, they all go off and get sent to a different application entirely. So for a short period of time, this application will be in use, and then stops being used until the same time next year. While the application is in use, no external sources will be touching the database at all.

When the (Node) server starts up, it loads everything from the database, into an object literal on the server.

The client-side of this application, on a very basic level, makes requests (to an API on the server) for data, and sends updated versions of records back to the server once they've been processed.

So here's where it gets weird: Let's say I don't want to have the client-side application have to directly retrieve records from the database, nor do I want it to be able to write to them. So the data from the entire database already exists in memory on the server. There's a module on the server that can handle changing the representation of that data already (again, because the client application only interacts with APIs on the server, the database module exists to facilitate this).

Multiple users access the system at once, but due to the way the system works, it is not possible for two users to be sent the same record, so two users will never be sending an update back for the same record (records are processed individually, and sequentially).

So, let's say that I decided that, since I was already managing all of this data in memory on the server, I would just send an updated version of the current data, in its entirety, back to the database, every time it changed.

The question is, where does this rank on the crazy scale?

Performance, writing an entire database rather than single records, would obviously suffer. But, in a database that is *only* read from once (on start-up of the application), is that even a concern? If every operation other than "Write all the stuff when any of the stuff changes" happened in memory on the server, does it matter how long those updates actually take? If a new update to the database comes in whilst it's being updated, surely SQL will take care of this?

It feels like the *correct* way to do this of course, is to have each user directly getting their info from the database, and directly making updates to the database too (or at least interacting with API endpoints to make this happen), but, is just...not doing that, utter lunacy?

Like I said, I know it's weird, but other than the fact that "it feels kind of wrong", I'm not sure I'm convinced that it is in fact entirely wrong. So I figured that this place would have an opinion.

The way that I think it currently works is:

[SQL DB] is updated whenever a change happens on {in-memory DB}
{in-memory DB} is updated in various ways based on API calls to the server
 makes requests for data, and sends updates to data, both of which are processed on the in-memory DB

Multiple requests can happen at the same time from the application, but mutliple users can not see the same record, because records are allocated to a given user before they're sent

Multiple updates can come from multiple users, each of which ultimately ends in the entire SQL database being saved to with the contents of the in-memory DB.

(Note: I'm not saying "is this the best way to do this". I'm just asking, is there a significant argument for caring about the performance of a database being written to, if it's not going to be read from again unless the server needs to be restarted)

Comment: The problem that I see is concurrency: let's say that rewriting the database takes 5 minutes. You would have to make the api handler async to prevent the client web browser from timing out -- no problem there, really. But what happens when Bob submits his change, and then Sally, 1 minute later? Bob's request is still busy writing (the entire dataset, as you were saying), and Sally's request wants to do the same? You would have to block (long timeout + transaction lock or cheap-n-nasty with a boolean and setTimeout) to prevent data inconsistency.

Comment: And if you do lock out everything properly, assuming still the 5 minute save time, you are obviously hoping that you don't get more than 1 request per 5-minute window, on average, for however long it takes to take down your service or database. Also, whilst locking and waiting to push the entire database, you run the chance of losing a users changes -- as the changes are only in memory: if the api service dies -- changes are lost.

Comment: I am a little lost with what you are suggesting but it sounds like you are saying you have a Middleware server that is loading the entire SQL database into memory.  The middleware is being update/communicated with by the client side users.  And now you are wondering whether you are going to incrementally update the SQL by middleware or just always send the entire dataset back to sql.  I guess what would be the benefit of the later?  You don't have to do change tracking?  You will definitely have a much larger performance impact on your network backbone/hardware, SQL server....

Comment: Bulk database writes could generate a huge amount of logs, depending on how they are implemented. Archive log files are basically a register of every individual record written to the DB. So you are able to restore a DB from backup and then roll it forward (using logs) to the present moment. I really don't see any upside to this design. In theory you could cache files that are being saved to a USB drive in memory, then write them to the drive every 10 minutes. It wouldn't be a very good design decision, though.

Comment: Hah, thanks for the input - Don't get me wrong, I'm not suggesting this was a *good* idea, so much as getting a full understanding for why it's a bad idea. This wasn't really a "design decision", it was just the way things ended up because of the fact that the "mock" database was just a JSON file, so reading from it and writing to it all at once made sense during the initial build of the services. 

Then I just thought "What if I just leave it working like this?", and figured I'd poll opinions on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think that I would do, in this situation, is to add an attribute to each cached record to indicate that the record is "dirty."  In other words, that something has been done to it, by someone, since it was originally read from the database.

(You could also add an attribute that indicates that someone "has this particular record 'checked-out,'" so that you can be *sure* that two users are no updating the same record at the same time.)

At some convenient moment, you can then walk through the collection, posting the "dirty" records back to the database.  Use an SQL Transaction, not only for efficiency but also to be sure that the final update to the database is atomic.

You will need to be very mindful of the possibility of race-conditions. One possible strategy is to use a Unix timestamp as a "dirty" indicator.  A record is selected for posting to the database only if its "dirty-time" is greater-than or equal-to the timestamp when the commit-process was last run.

(And, P.S.:  *"no, I've seen even 'weirder' things than this, in all my crazy years in this crazy business ...)*

Comment: Thanks for this - I do already have an attribute that records who has each record checked out, so that side of it is in place already. But yes, I can see that your suggestion of updating the latest set of 'dirty' records regularly is far more sensible than my admittedly cavalier "just do the whole bloody lot all of the time" approach. :D Again, I did't think this was a *good* idea, I just wanted clarification on just how much of a *bad* idea it was. You may be somewhat unsurprised to learn that I don't exactly have decades of experience with databases. :D

Many thanks. :)

Comment: *Meh...* "Who does? We're all just *really good* at faking it!"  **;-)** Yeah, total-replacement *is* "a really bad idea."

Comment: Now, *another* idea, that you might wish to percolate among the gray-cells of your cranium, is this: that, instead of loading "the whole damned database" into memory at program-startup, you instead retrieve the records **on demand**. Start with an *empty* hash. Each time the user requests a record that's not in-memory yet, go get it, and add it to the hash.

Comment: You might *also* wish to ponder whether the "grab the whole thing into memory" strategy is, *today,* "a 'no-longer necessary necessity' of another time." Hardware TODAY was an impossible-dream "back then." (Yeah, I was there ...) *(koff, koff ...)*

Comment: ... but then again, if *(as you said in your comment to the previous post)* "it once was a JSON file ..." *(and it actually **worked** ...)*  Heck, you just might still be able to get away with *that* strategy!

Comment: Mike to add to it depending on user2634525's version of sql he might have in-memory tables available and then maybe not bother with the caching at all in middleware if only the client is doing the modifications......

Comment: Yup... there are *"so damned many"* options available now, than existed when I once paid $1,400 for an *i**2**86**sx*** machine with *1 **mega**byte* ... **:-O** ... of memory ... and considered that I had just bought "the top of the line" ... because, in fact, I **had!** *(koff, koff ... "these **kids** today" ...)* Certainly, today, the question sometimes needs to be asked as to whether an existing application "really ought to be" reworked.  *However,* there always remains the question of whether it is wise to provoke a sleeping dragon, for an app that's used just once a year.

Comment: You know what, I think I've missed something very obvious here too. This system needs to read in a database, process every record in it, and then once they're all processed, the entire database gets picked up by a different application (don't ask - none of this is my idea)...

So actually, it doesn't even need to write to the database more than once. :P No-one else uses the database at all during the time this system is use. So why not just read the database into memory, save it to a JSON file, let the system do its thing but just overwrite the JSON file on every save, then when...

Comment: ...all records are processed, just do a single write at that point. Yes that write will still be "write everything", but it'll only happen once. :P 

Still may not be *the right* thing to do technically, but it's better than my last stupid idea surely. :D

Comment: (Which I realise now on re-reading, was actually one of Mike's many suggestions!)